# IIS application and SQL trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-applications, iis-7

I am having an issue with an IIS application and SQL.
I can log into the SQL server directly with the username:vtc2
[image]

and I can access the SQL server using the ODBC connection using the same username: vtc2
[image]

this is my ini file for the application:

```
DSN=VTE
Driver=SQL Server
Server=MLAERP01\VTIMECARD
Database=vTimeCard
UID=vtc2
PWD=
```

BUT when I try to access the website directly it gives me an error:
[image]

and the SQL server log says:
[image]

web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="timecard.dll" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ISAPI-dll" />
            <add name="ISAPI-dll" path="*.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\Virtual Time+Expense\Timecard.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="bitness32" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please help!  I need to get this done as soon as possible.  I do not know what to look for as to why the username fails through the website...

Comment: Can you show the full connection string?

Comment: The password i left blank intentionally but it is correct because I use the same password when I connect to the SQL server and the ODBC connection...  This is a pre-built application, not mine.  I do not have the string, it references the ini file for connection and yet still fails to connect.

Comment: web.config <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="timecard.dll" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ISAPI-dll" />
            <add name="ISAPI-dll" path="*.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\Virtual Time+Expense\Timecard.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="bitness32" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>